# ArrayList, objects overwriting

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make a arraylist with user objects, however when trying to add a new object to the list, it just seems to work partly.

**1st Issue:** When doing a .size() on the list after having added the object, and confirmed via system.out.println that the list contains this object, it still doesn't increase it's size.

Lets say that I have a list containing 100 elements, and when doing a .size() it outputs that. However when then trying to add a new element, the .size() still returns 100 but .toString() returns the new object as well.

**2nd Issue:**

When using .add() on my list it seems to add the object to the list once, but if I try to call that method again to create yet another user, it just overwrites the previous one.

How can that be?

Here is a code snippet for my method "createPerson()":

```
public void createPerson(){
        int pid = handler.getPersonsCount();
        pid += 1;
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What's your name?");
        String mail = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What's your e-mail?");
        String phone = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What's your phone nummber?");
        String city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Which city are you currently living in?");
        String dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        handler.addPerson(new Person(pid, name, mail, phone, city, dateTime));
        showMsg("The following has been added:" + pid
                + "\nName: " + name
                + "\nMail: " + mail
                + "\nNumber: " + phone
                + "\nCity: " + city
                + "\nDatetime: " + dateTime);
        System.out.println(handler.PersonsArraylist.toString());
        System.out.println("Size: " + handler.getPersonsCount());
});
}
```

handler.getPersonsCount() :

```
public int getPersonsCount() {
        return PersonsArraylist.size();
    }
```

handler.addPerson() :

```
public void addPerson(Person person) {
        PersonsArraylist.add(person);
    }
```

If needed, I have pushed it to Github, so you can browse the entire code: [EENielsen/personseacher_oo](https://github.com/EENielsen/personseacher_oo)

Comment: what's "PersonsArraylist"? Last time I did check `ArrayList` was not broken ([proof](https://ideone.com/uqUFf1)) so can you post a MCVE?

Comment: ArrayList<Person> PersonsArraylist = new ArrayList();

Comment: For clarity reasons please use the Java coding conventions which state if `PersonsArraylist` is the name of a field it should start with a lower case character, i.e. `personsArraylist`. As it is now it looks much like a class.

Comment: Any chance you're accidentially recreating the handler or the list inside?

Comment: Your MCVE is not complete enough, so it's hard to comment. But my bet would go that the addPerson does not add to the same instance of PersonsArrayList then handler.PersonsArraylist

Comment: I think you might just be miscounting.

Comment: where r u initializing your handler. may be here handler is initializing for every add

Comment: I'm pretty new to Java. @Thomas I can't find the anywhere the handle should be recreated nor the list. I've uploaded it all to Github, https://github.com/EENielsen/personseacher_oo - Not sure if that makes it easier?

Comment: You coded quite well, apart from the coding convention mentioned. So either the object with createPerson or **handler is created anew**. The pid would best be set in addPerson, as one would do in a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `showInterface` doesn't seem right.

```
private void showInterface() {
    try {
        Interface test = new Interface();
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Interface.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

It seems that after you execute a command, you are creating a new interface, which in turn creates a new `PersonHandler`.

You need to at least remove the `new Interface()` in `showInterface` method.

Perhaps this is what you were after?

```
private void showInterface() {
    try {
        createStartMenu();
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Interface.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: You're welcome and "welcome" to programming java. You're doing great so far :)

Answer (score 1):

It might not be directly related to your current problem but I'd like to share a few observations on your code:

- In `PersonHandler` the fields `PersonData` and `PersonsArray` seem to be only used in the constructor, so they should be method local variables.
- You encapsulate `PersonsArraylist` quite well but then also make it available to the outside world via `getPersons()` (which btw seesm to miss the generics on the return type). This way someone on the outside could mess with the list which might be the cause of your issues.
- In `sortPersons()` you're doing the sorting yourself. If this isn't for learning purposes I'd recommend using `Collections.sort()` instead.
- As vikingsteve already answered in `showInterface()` you're recreating the interface which you then don't use.
- In terms of general design you shouldn't mix data handling and ui code, e.g. what you're doing in the handler (showing a dialog etc.).
- In `deletePerson()` and `deletePersons()` you should recreate the pids since the indices of all persons after those that are deleted will change and you defined pid = index (i.e. in `getPerson(int pid)` you use the pid directly to access the list).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I started learning Java with my Computer Science class in start february, so I still have a lot to learn - Every advice accepted :-)

 I've been trying Collections as well, but our teacher would like us to manually sort it for, as you said, learning.

I tried to seperate the code into handling and ui, but still seems like a b***ch to do so(I got a lot to learn). For deletePerson() and deletePersons(), I would just need to call my method resetPersonsId() corect?

Comment: @EmilElkjærNielsen as for your last question: I'd move that method out of the handler and into the ui code (`Interface` in your case which btw is a misleading name and which could be split up - but you'll learn that eventually, especially with development practice and experience). For someone who started 4 weeks ago your code looks actually quite good.

Comment: @EmilElkjærNielsen your comment now is different so mine above was meant to answer the question you deleted :) - As for your question on `deletePerson()` etc.: ids shouldn't change since that would often break a lot of other code (in fact an object almost never changes its identity). Thus I'd probably rather rewrite `getPerson(int id)` to look for the person with that id and not use it as an index (you could use a map id-> Person for that).

Comment: Only got previous experience with Python from high school and then many long nights learning myself PHP and playing around with C# and so on (Not expert or full-stack at any point though :D ), but thank you!

I think it's best if I hold off using Collections etc(Which I am pretty sure map is a part of? ) until we've been taught something about it :)

As for adding a new person, is it better pratice that I under "addPerson(Person p)" sets the ID? So it would look somewhat like this? http://pastebin.com/kSWsJgEe

Comment: @EmilElkjærNielsen yes, you can consider maps being part of the collections framework, although not being a  `Collection` itself (it doesn't implement the interface but provides one when calling `values()`). It probably depends on the requirements but setting the id outside the method might be fine (you sometimes get ids from someone else) in which case you'd need to check for duplicates though. Setting the id in `addPerson()` would be ok as well but setting it in the constructor then seems a bit misleading and error prone (you could forget to replace it). ... (to be continued)

Comment: ... So I'd either not set the id in the constructor or pass the data to `addPerson()` and create the instance inside.